# One to Many with a join table and an optional relationship in Entity Framework 4.1 Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

Again with a legacy database that cannot be changed and using Entity Framework 4.1 with the Fluent API to read data only.

```
public class Client
{
  [Key]
  public int ClientID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set ;}

  public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
  [Key]
  public int PhoneID { get; set; }
  public string Number { get; set; }

  public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class ClientPhone
{
  [Key]
  [Column(Order=0)]
  public int ClientID { get; set; }

  [Key]
  [Column(Order=1)]
  public int PhoneID { get; set; }
}
```

I want the Client to have many Phones, but the Phones should have only an optional Client.
**Note: Phones should have only 0|1 Client. I do NOT want a many to many.**
So I've tried the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>()
  .HasMany(c => c.Phones)
  .WithOptional(p => p.Client)
  .Map(m =>
    {
      m.MapKey("ClientID");
      m.ToTable("ClientPhone");
    });

modelBuilder.Entity<Phone>()
  .HasOptional(p => p.Client)
  .WithMany(c => c.Phones)
  .Map(m =>
    {
      m.MapKey("PhoneID");
      m.ToTable("ClientPhone");
    });
```

I've tried a couple of permutations usually getting an error about "Each property name in a type must be unique."

Thanks for the help.

**EDIT WITH ANSWER**

Here are the modifications I made to the entity classes. It is possible to navigate from **one Client to many Phones** and from **one Phone to one Client**, but you must go through the ClientPhone join table.

```
[Table("Client")]
public class Client
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int ClientID { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set ;}

  public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; } // Client has * Phones
}

[Table("Phone")]
public class Phone
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  public int PhoneID { get; set; }

  public string Number { get; set; }

  public virtual Client Client { get; set; } // Phone has 0|1 Client
}

[Table("ClientPhone")]
public class ClientPhone
{
  // Removed the Key attribute
  public int ClientID { get; set; }

  [Key] // Left the Key on the 0|1 side
  [ForeignKey("Phone")]
  public int PhoneID { get; set; }

  public virtual Client Client { get; set; } // One Client
  public virtual Phone Phone { get; set; } // One Phone
}
```

Comment: How are your tables defined? What tables do you have in the database and what relations are configured? If database contains many-to-many and junction table you cannot map it as one-to-many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you don't need to specify the relationship between phone and client two times here. Just use only one  like this.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().HasMany(c => c.Phones).WithMany(i => i.Clients)
                .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("PhoneID")
                    .MapRightKey("ClientID")
                    .ToTable("ClientPhone"));
```

you do not need to have models to map relationship tables like "ClientPhone" because EF will take care of it .If you have a legacy database you can customize your mappings as in my answer. And as @Ladislav Mrnka said for one to many rel.ationship in database level you do not want to keep a separate table for the relationship. For that ,

```
public class Client
{
  [Key]
  public int ClientID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set ;}

  public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
  [Key]
  public int PhoneID { get; set; }
  public string Number { get; set; }

  public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

this will be enough with EF. It will create two tables with **clientId** column in **Phone** table to keep the relationship.

The problem is you have separate table for relationship in your legacy database.I think legacy database is defined for many-to-many relationship.Think twice your domain logic again.

If you want to keep one-to-many relationship what I think is you can define in domain level many-to-many relationship (phone have many clients and client have many phones in model clases) and in you business layer add validations to keep only one **client** for a **Phone**.

Comment: I updated the question to be more explicit... I need Phones to have 0|1 Client only.

Comment: Thanks Jayantha for your thorough answer. Between this and @Ladislav Mrnka answers, the answers are complete. I believe my posted solution works for my situation, but still your answer is probable.

Answer (score 1):

One to many relation doesn't have join (junction) table. If your database uses junction table to connect Client to Phone you must use many-to-many relation (Phone can have many clients) as @Jayantha described.

Comment: I think I've got it working per my scenario, the question wasn't perfectly clear. You can use a join table to make a 1-to-many on one side and a 1-to-1 on the other side, which is what I wanted to do.

Comment: In such case the junction table is completely redundant.

Comment: I added my solution and would be glad to learn how I can remove that redundancy, and improve on my attempt.