# One-To-Many relationship with join(bridge) table

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to implement the following model:
I have a dictionary table (`ProductOffer` Table) that contains a few records (just like editable enum). Also, I have a main table(`ChangeNet`) that should store a collection of `ProductOffer`. The dictionary should not have foreign keys to the main table, so I decided to create additional table `ChangeNetToProductOffer` containing foreign keys of both tables.

```
ChangeNet table      CNtoPO table       ProductOffer table (dictionary)
--------             ------------       --------
CNId      --->       CNId         --->  POId
name                 POId               Name
```

Scheme:
[image]
Models:

```
public class ChangeNet
{
    public int Id{get;set;}

    public virtual ICollection<ChangeNetToProductOffer> offers { get; set; }
}

public class ProductOffer
{       
    [Key]        
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] //Allows to insert your own primary key        
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }       
}

/// <summary>
/// Relationship table between ChangeNet & ProductOffer dictionary
/// </summary>
public class ChangeNetToProductOffer {

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ChangeNetId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChangeNetId")]
    public virtual ChangeNet ChangeNet { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ProductOfferId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProductOfferId")]
    public virtual ProductOffer ProductOffer { get; set; }

}
```

Generated migration scheme:

```
CreateTable(
            "dbo.ChangeNetToProductOffer",
            c => new
                {
                    ChangeNetId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    ProductOfferId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ChangeNetId, t.ProductOfferId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ChangeNet", t => t.ChangeNetId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.ProductOffer", t => t.ProductOfferId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.ChangeNetId)
            .Index(t => t.ProductOfferId);
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPut]
    [Route("api/cn/update")]
    public IHttpActionResult Update(ChangeNetEditViewModelBase modelBase)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Ok(new ApiResultError("Object not valid for ChangeNet"));
        var item = Update(modelBase);
        if (item != null && item.Id > 0)
            return Ok(new ApiResultSuccess<ChangeNet>(item, "ChangeNet successfully updated"));
        return Ok(new ApiResultError("Can't update ChangeNet"));
    }

 public ChangeNet Update(ChangeNetEditViewModelBase modelBase) {
   try {
            var items = _context.ChangeNets.Include(x => x.ProductOffers.Select(p=>p.ProductOffer));
            var changeNet = items.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == modelBase.Id);
            if (changeNet == null) return null;


            Mapper.Map(modelBase, changeNet); //copy properties
            changeNet.name = "test";

            _context.SaveChanges(); // I GET AN ERROR HERE               

            return changeNet;
        }
        catch (Exception exception) {
            _logger.Error(exception); 
            return null;
        }
    }
```

When I try to save changes I get an error on `_context.SaveChanges();`:
    **Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity of type 'Models.ChangeNetToProductOffer' have the same primary key value. Ensure that explicitly set primary key values are unique. Ensure that database-generated primary keys are configured correctly in the database and in the Entity Framework model. Use the Entity Designer for Database First/Model First configuration. Use the 'HasDatabaseGeneratedOption" fluent API or 'DatabaseGeneratedAttribute' for Code First configuration.**

What am I doing wrong?

**TEMPORARY SOLUTION**

I've found temporary solution. I remove all records related to changeNet before `_context.SaveChanges();`

```
private void RemoveProductOffersFromChangeNet(int changeNetId)
    {
        //Remove all ProductOffers related to the current ChangeNet
        var itemsToDelete = _context.ChangeNetToProductOffers.Where(po => po.ChangeNetId == changeNetId);
        foreach (var item in itemsToDelete) _context.ChangeNetToProductOffers.Remove(item);
    }

public ChangeNet Update(ChangeNetEditViewModelBase modelBase) {

            //some code
            RemoveProductOffersFromChangeNet(changeNet.Id);

            _context.SaveChanges();              

            return changeNet;

    }
```

But I don't like this solution. I want EF to do all work (check changes and update, delete or add records)

Comment: When inserting data is there any row in CnToPo that shows relation between ChangeNet and ProductOffer ?

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev, yes.

Comment: Why don't you have an `Id` column in `ChangeNetToProductOffer` and set it as your primary key

Comment: The model looks fine. In order to tell you what's wrong, we need to see the code which fails.

Comment: @AbdulSamad, in this case it just inserts new records without updating and deleting

Comment: Maybe in CNtoPO  table, CNId was considered as primary key. Add an ID as primary key. As it is one to many relationship, if you try to add the same CNId again, it gives the error. Try adding an id field as primary key  to CNtoPO table.

Comment: @Chidambaram, if I add `id` as primary key in CNtoPO table then EF just inserts rows to CNtoPO table without updating.

Comment: @Nolesh, got it. This link with similar issue may be helpful i guess. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034185/one-to-many-with-a-join-table-and-an-optional-relationship-in-entity-framework-4

Comment: @Chidambaram, looks good. Tomorrow I'll try your link. Thank you.

Comment: This question is unanswerable (and should be closed as such) if we don't see all code before `SaveChanges`.

Comment: `Mapper.Map` is the problem. Working with related data in EF is not so simple. AutoMapper is not good in general for mapping DTOs to Entities. At least take a look and try utilize [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection)

Comment: @IvanStoev, Thank you so much! You was right! Mapper.Map was the problem! Now it works like a charm! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Ivan Stoyev, I was able to solve my issue. The problem was related to `Mapper.map`. It copied properties in wrong way. So, I need to assign `changeNet.ProductOffers` property directly.

```
public ChangeNet Update(ChangeNetEditViewModelBase modelBase) {
try {
        var items = _context.ChangeNets.Include(x => x.ProductOffers.Select(p=>p.ProductOffer));
        var changeNet = items.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == modelBase.Id);
        if (changeNet == null) return null;

        Mapper.Map(modelBase, changeNet); //IT COPIES NESTED PROPS IN WRONG WAY!!!
        changeNet.name = "test";

        changeNet.ProductOffers = modelBase.ProductOffers; //ASSIGN DIRECTLY!!!

        _context.SaveChanges();        

        return changeNet;
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        _logger.Error(exception); 
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now it works like a charm!